# How can I update the default version of Spring that Intellij provides?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

When I create a Spring project in IntelliJ IDEA, it suggests I use Spring 4.1.6. I want to use 4.2.1 (which I can do after creating the project).

[image]

Where can I make the change?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can change that yourself without an upgrade but you can allow it to create it with that version then manually change it your `pom.xml` file.

For example,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also provide a property that an be used on all your Spring dependencies and then you only have to change it one place.

For example,

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

Then use it like...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I do - which is fine of course but it just feels wrong that I have to do it like that. Hard-coded to 4.1.6 by IntelliJ huh?

Comment: @MeinFarzer, IIRC the latest version of STS generates a 3x!!

Comment: Good name BTW, Chief.

Comment: @MeinFarzer, there may be a way to download the specific version you want and then choose the directory instead of choosing download. I'll add it to the answer if [this](http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/) or [this](http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/4.2.1.RELEASE/) helps. I think the reasoning is they can't guarantee all the features will be supported. BTW, 15 EAP still targets 4.1.6...